# How to get a reference to the bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've been trying to use the datepicker here... http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It has code examples showing how to program the API. e.g.

```
var picker = $('#datetimepicker'l).data('datetimepicker');
picker.setLocalDate(null);
```

I don't seem to be able to get the 'picker' reference though. 'data' is a function but it returns null. Thus I can't call the API methods.

How do I get a reference?

Furthermore, can anyone explain what is happening with the 'data' call? What does the string 'datetimepicker' refer to?

My code...

```
<div id="expirationDate" class="input-append date">
  <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" readonly id="txtBxExpirationDate" type="text" style="width: 250px;" required />
  <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>

var picker = $('#expirationDate').datetimepicker();

alert(picker);
alert(picker.data);
alert(picker.data('datepicker'));
```

The alerts give me an Object, a juicy looking function implementation and a null.

Comment: Grabbing a reference to the one on the documentation page works fine: `$('#datetimepicker1').data('datetimepicker')`.  Only thing I see wrong in your example is the "1" should be inside the quotes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo/syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a typo in the doc.. remove the `l` after `'#datetimepicker'`

```
var picker = $('#datetimepicker').data('datetimepicker');
```

[Demo](http://bootply.com/60789)

Comment: Yes I spotted that. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Does the `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({..});` work otherwise? Any console errors?

Comment: I can't check the console right now but yes the picker works ok.

Comment: Are you able to post more of your code?

Comment: You're right, but the typo is that the "1" should be in the quotes, since that's the actual `id` for the `<div>` on the page.

Comment: Updated question with code.

Comment: The code you posted shows `alert(picker.data('datepicker'));` .. It has to say .data('datetimepicker') -- also picker returns the API methods for the plugin so that you can use picker.setLocalDate(), etc.. please see my Demo again

Comment: I read your last comment just after realising my mistake. What a stupid error!